# Troubles Installing R Word Cloud Package - Mint 17.1

Tags: r, linux-mint, word-cloud

Attempting to install the R Word-Cloud Package into User Library, however receiving the following error.  Looks like it successfully downloads package, but bombs during installation.  I suspect the issue is resulting from trying to install in a User Library and the second g++ line, but not sure how to correct.  I am running Mint 17.1 64-bit.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
install.packages("wordcloud", lib="/media/Data/RPackages")
trying URL 'http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/wordcloud_2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 40861 bytes (39 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 39 KB

.Rprofile: Setting CMU repositoryn
* installing *source* package ‘wordcloud’ ...
** package ‘wordcloud’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/media/Data/RPackages/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c layout.cpp -o layout.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o wordcloud.so layout.o .Rprofile: Setting CMU repositoryn -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
g++: error: .Rprofile:: No such file or directory
g++: error: Setting: No such file or directory
g++: error: CMU: No such file or directory
g++: error: repositoryn: No such file or directory
make: *** [wordcloud.so] Error 1**strong text**
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘wordcloud’
* removing ‘/media/Data/RPackages/wordcloud’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘wordcloud’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpdScavH/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  In my .Rprofile file, I had the following:

```
cat(".Rprofile: Setting CMU repositoryn")
r = getOption("repos") # hard code the Oakridge repo for CRAN
r["CRAN"] = "http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/"
options(repos = r)
rm(r)
```

I removed the first line changing it to the following:

```
r = getOption("repos") # hard code the Oakridge repo for CRAN
r["CRAN"] = "http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/"
options(repos = r)
rm(r)
```

Restarted R and install worked.  I guess the WordCount package didn't like the first line.